Fan not working on Gigabyte GTX 550 Ti - Possible missing component (C503)?
I'm facing an issue with the fan not working on my Gigabyte GTX 550 Ti (Model: GV-N550D5-1GI). At first, I thought it was just a broken fan. I also own a similar card, the GTX 550 Ti from Gigabyte (Model: GV-N550 OC-1GI), which is faulty for unknown reasons, but its fan still worked—it would spin up at BIOS startup.
I swapped the fan from the faulty card to the first one, but it still doesn’t work. I tried various programs like Fan Speed and MSI Afterburner, but none of them can get the fan spinning.
While investigating, I noticed something unusual on the PCB. Unfortunately, I couldn’t find any schematics, and I’m not an expert, so I don’t know if this is how it’s supposed to be. The PCBs on both cards are similar, but there are slight differences. One small detail caught my attention: a component labeled C503. It exists on the OC model, but on the non-OC card, it looks like it might have fallen off or is missing.
Could the missing C503 component be causing the fan not to work? What does this component do? The IC near it is labeled ncp5395t.
I also found another strange component - LB518, also missing.
Below photos od GPU cpomared to oc version and board from same card from auction. It has got these components.
Not working fan

OC version with working fan

Not working fan

GPU from internet

GPU from internet


Used-but-working  GTX 550 Tis go for about $15 on ebay, at least ones local to me. GTX 750 Tis, a whole two generations newer, go for only about twice that. (I've not seen a gigabyte one, though. They're mostly EVGA.) It might not be worth the effort to try to repair, if availability in your region is similar.

As for C503, it looks like a bypass capacitor for the IC U501 (likely some kind of auxiliary processor, bus controller, or housekeeping circuit). In all likelihood, they determined it was unnecessary in later revisions of the product and left it off to save a few cents--this is pretty common for bypass caps.

It is my old card and i Ask only for educational purpose

And what about this next to fan cable? IT is strange what you said because card from internet and mine are signed as rev: 1.0

Later revisions of the product, not of the board. If there was a new revision of the board, they would likely remove the capacitor footprint altogether.

@Hearth I disagree. C503 looks like just nudged off solder joints, not like it's an unpopulated from the manufacturing.

Ok, thanks for explanation. So i do not know why fan does not work.

Both missing components have weld remnants btw. But i heard that boards can be so sloppily produced. I do not know...

@Justme It might. It's hard to tell if that's just a trick of the light in the photos.

Higher resolution photos would be helpful. I'm also inclined to say that it looks like the component has fallen off, likely during 2-sided assembly. Gigabyte are infamous for their very low quality products if you ask me. I've only ever been forced to RMA a total of 3 gfx cards over the years, all of them Gigabyte. Didn't matter if Nvidia or AMD.

@newman PCBs aren't welded... they are soldered.

Sorry, i meant soldered of course. I am trying to swap these elements from spare card, OC version. They have same markings on pcb. After that i will check it.

@newman If you have a capacitance meter you can just measure it while the part is soldered off. A qualified guess is that this looks like a bulk cap for the IC supply since it has larger package (0805?) that the rest (0603?). Then a value somewhere between 1uF and 10uF would be very likely. And if so it is a pretty important component, more so than regular decoupling caps.

Both the pads for C503 and LB518 look like there has been a component soldered originally but now torn off. If the were left unpopulated at the factory, they would look cleaner like there has never been a component.
LB518 looks like a filter for the fan as it is near it and it could explain why fan does not work. Also missing C503 could cause anything, from instability to simply not working product.
Without schematics, or reverse-engineering the board further, and without data sheet for the IC to which the capacitor is likely connected, there really is nothing much to do.

Board schematics propably do not exist on the internet. Can i gues which capacitor is it by it size for example to add it to the board?

@newman No you can't guess which capacitor it is based on size or colour. If you know where it connects to and what it does, maybe from the datasheet of the nearby chip NCP5395, but if it is a current sense filter cap, the value is application specific what kind of filtering is needed to work properly.

I replaced both components with ones from the other card, and the fan started working. The card is also working. In the evening, I'll run stress tests to check if I didn't break anything else :D

@Justme In this case the larger package used for this particular cap makes it somewhat possible to guess though: likely a supply bulk cap for the IC. And if so probably >1uF.

@newman Like mentioned in the answer LB518 is very likely a bead inductor and as such very likely placed in series either with the fan supply or activation signal. For the purpose to filter out EMI from the fan ("pi filter"). In that case if it is missing, the fan won't start, as either the supply or the activation signal is missing.
